# Difference between onbeforeunload and onunload

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, mobile-safari, onbeforeunload

What are the differences between onbeforeunload and onunload ?
Also I have a specific question related to it's use on the iPad...I have a page (myPage.html) where I am trying to show an alert when the page is closed (i.e. X is pressed to close the tab on iPad)

Now I tried using both window.onunload and window.onbeforeunload
Below are my findings on the iPad;

1. Using window.onunload , I am able to get an alert when user navigates to a different page from myPage.html (either by clicking on some link or doing a Google search while on myPage.html) . However nothing happens when the tab is closed from the minimized view (X)
2. Using window.onbeforeunload, I neither get an alert even if the user navigates to a different page from myPage.html OR if he closes the tab (X) from the minimized view.

I wanted to know if there is any alternate way to fix this issue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`onunload` is responsible for executing an instruction when the page is closed. It also causes issue with IE and AJAX.

`onbeforeunload` is more efficient because it does not run in competition with the actual closing of the window and is triggered before `onunload`

I know Opera used to not acknowledge `onbeforeunload` - not sure if they've fixed that, but I always register the listener for both to be safe:

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = (function(){...
```

Comment: Thx a lot for that...But any idea about the iPad implementation ?

Comment: window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = (function(){..., will execute the function twice if browser has no issues with both the events.

Comment: @noboundaries-how to fix this fix this two times firing?

Comment: @ShahidulHaque You will need to write code that will detect second firing and ignore it.

Answer (score 27):

Adding with AlienWebguy's ans, to avoid dual calls at the browsers that support both events,

```
var onBeforeUnLoadEvent = false;

window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload= function(){
if(!onBeforeUnLoadEvent){
  onBeforeUnLoadEvent = true;
  //your code here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 15):

`onbeforeunload`:

- Called before unloading begins
- [MDN tells me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) you can cancel the closing of the page using `event.preventDefault();`
- or by returning a non-void value (ie a value != 0), the page will pop up a confirmation dialog that allows the user to choose to cancel the close
- MDN also says Opera 12 and up support onbeforeunload - looks like its supported it for a while now

`onunload`:

- Called after unloading has begun, but before any resource deallocation (its not clear to me what exactly *is* done during this period)
- Its too late to cancel the page close at this point

The only reason I can think of why you would want to use `onunload` over `onbeforeunload` would be where your `onunload` code could take some significant time, and don't want the user to see a window that hangs while closing.

Comment: If the page is going to be viewed in some iPhones, you'll find that the `onbeforeunload` won't be processed.

Answer (score 11):

One significant difference (other than cancelability) between the `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` is that the former is triggered for download links and the latter is not. Example: `<a href="https://somewhere.com/thething.zip">download</a>` will trigger the `onbeforeunload` handler, but not the `onunload`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Chrome. Do you have any documentation on this?