# Exit browser confirmation in javascript - HOW TO ?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a flex application. In the wrapper jsp of the flex application, an html page, i have to capture the browser close event with an alert "DO you wish to close?", if the user clicks "yes", i have to call a flex function to handle the event. Can any one help !

Comment: There is already a question answered on capturing browser close event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event.

Comment: Please don't do this. It is really annoying to users.

Answer (score 2):

On your `body` tag, add onunload event:

```
<body onunload="doStuffHere();">
...
</body>
```

and in your JS function (`doStuffHere`) call Flex to handle the event.
If, eventually, doStuffHere returns false, it cancels the close event.

You can also use `onbeforedownload`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-cha) for more details. You can use both of them, [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload/6895605#6895605).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you have the [onBeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onbeforeunload) event, hook on to that. You only cannot alter its appearance.