# What is the difference between body.onunload and body.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between onbeforeunload and onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload)

What is the difference between body.onunload and body.onbeforeunload events? As I understand I can use onunload and onbeforeunload on any other HTML element. Is it useful? If so, when?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload

Answer (score 0):

`onBeforeUnload` isn't really supported - it's a Microsoft IE event.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [onunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) the main difference is that `onbeforeunload` is cancelable.

So for example, when you type in an answer in stackoverflow, don't post it but press something else, you'll get a dialog saying `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.` and a button to cancel.

Thats when onbeforeunload is useful.