# Which HTML tags support the onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

is any HTML tags support the onbeforeunload event likes window.onbeforeunload event.

the iframe tag has onload event not onbeforeunload.

Best Regards.

Comment: To get onbeforeunload with an iframe's document (that passes same origin policy), put the listener on `iframeNode.contentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `onbeforeunload` is not defined in any HTML specification. In the HTML5 draft, the [list of attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/section-index.html#attributes-1) mentions it as applying to the `body` element only; and it would hardly make sense for other elements (without redefinition). Regarding inline frames, use the attribute for the `body` element inside the framed document.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with the usage of "onbeforeunload". It is an Internet Explorer propietary event. I think that you can get the same functionallity using "onunload":
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

And, for better compatibility, use a Javascript framework like jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: For example, Firefox recognizes `onbeforeunload`. Regarding `unload`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload

Answer (score 0):

By looking at [the HTML5 working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents), *beforeunload* is only dispatched to *Window* objects.
If you want it to be dispatched to a node of your choice, listen for it on *Window* and then create a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Event/CustomEvent) which you dispatch to that node.

If you're interested in seeing when an *iframe* is about to unload and you're not running into the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you can place a listener on `.contentWindow` of the `<iframe>` which is the *Window* object for that iframe.

Answer (score -1):

The following link will provide you with a good insight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx

As far as I'm aware only the element tag can be used.

HTML Attribute

```
<element onbeforeunload = "handler(event)">
```

Comment: Constructs like `<element ...>` in IE documentation do not refer to an element with the name `element` but generically to HTML elements, and the construct basically just shows the format to be used in HTML.