# Difference in setting a function as anonymous

Tags: javascript, function, events

I know there is a great difference in 2 methods below:

```
a.onclick = function() {alert("Hi");};
```

and

```
a.onclick = (function() {alert("Hi");};)();
```

Why do people use the second method? The second should fire the alert() on page load but doesn't?

Why in [Difference between onbeforeunload and onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload) does the first guy uses the anonymous and the second uses the right one?

Comment: People who use the second method are unsuccessful people.

Comment: What @Pointy said.  The second method creates an anonymous function, then immediately calls it and stores the result (which is `undefined`) in `a.onclick`.

Comment: So they are all stupid using anonymous call to set an event. Thank you!

Comment: Unless the anonymous function returns a function.

Comment: The code in the post you linked is incomplete, a complete form could pretty much do anything.

Answer (score 4):

There are times when an anonymous, self-executing function is useful for event handlers. Your scenario is not one of them.

Here's one example. In this example, I'm using a scoped variable to keep track of how many times the handler is invoked, but in order to keep that variable from leaking into the outer scope, it has to be in a function; but in order to persist the value across event handler calls, it can't be initialized in the handler itself-- it needs to be bound in a closure.

```
a.onclick = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function (e) {
        ++counter;
        alert("Hi! This handler has been invoked " + counter + " times!");
    };
}());
```

So the self-executing function itself returns a function which is suitable as an onclick handler. However, it also has its own static state that it needs to keep track of even between invocations.

This is just one example of why it might be useful to use a self-executing function that returns a function for an event handler or other callback slot.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably get what you want by using the first method, i.e. storing a function in `onclick` field of object `a`.

The second case before storing invokes that function, which returns `undefined`, so it is equivalent of

```
a.onclick = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who find the whole anonymous function thing unreadable:

```
a.onclick = a_onclick;
var counter = 0;
function a_onclick()
{
  counter++;
  alert("Hi! This handler has been invoked " + counter + " times!");
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenally/aXKL7/