# How to capture back button click event in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to execute a function when the user clicks on the back button of a browser. For chrome & firefox, I have achieved it with html5 "popstate" event. I'm not being able to capture the back button click event in IE8. In my case, I need to capture the back button click event even if the url/location hash doesn't change. Anyone to help ??

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/680865/1010918)

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var msg = "Do you really want to leave this page?"
        // For IE and Firefox
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = msg;
        }
        // For Safari / chrome
       return msg;
     };
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I guess,, this will work for refresh button also.. My requirement is to catch only back button click event..

Answer (score 0):

Well, from google search I found this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1829278.aspx?Detect%20Browser%20refresh%20reload%20button%20click%20in%20all%20browsers), it seems that you can differentiate between a refresh and a click back:

```
window.onunload = function(e) {
// Firefox || IE
e = e || window.event;

var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;

if(y < 0)  alert("Window closed");
else alert("Window refreshed");

}
```

[event.pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.pageY) | [event.clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.clientY): detect the location the mouse.
[window.onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload):is responsible for executing an instruction when the page is closed.

I didn't try it myself, but hope this would help.