# How can i redirect page when i close the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to reditect the page when i close the browser close button.I have this code but it is not working.Please help me.how can i do this.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (window.confirm('yes/no?'))
    {
        window.location="http://www.google.com";
    }
    else
    {
          alert('staying this page');
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895564/difference-between-onbeforeunload-and-onunload

Comment: No..not use that link

Comment: does this mean. its not working ?