# jquery The unload() method not work?

Tags: jquery

According to w3school The unload() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0. and these code not worl also

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

any new method for doing that task please help me
this is example code i am building live chat application when user close browser  update value to database

Comment: Try using without jQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895605/3773265

Comment: i try not work also live chat not work

Answer (score 0):

Use pure javascript code not jquery to achieve that.

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
alert("Good Bye");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Bye now!";
};
```